# Store python classes as pickles in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

I am porting a Python investing application to Google App Engine. Every market that you can trade in is a plugin: for example the stocks trading and FOREX trading are all plugins.

The application stores the *portfolio* (which is a Portfolio class instance containing the active investments (class instances) and history) as a pickle. However you can't write to the disk, and it seems a bit crude to use pickles in the Datastore as a blob, and pickles are also slow and CPU intensive (no cPickle).

Does anyone have any ideas how I can store all the current investments, and the history to the datastore without using large and intensive pickles?

Thank you

Ps. webapp or Django?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use the Datastore data models, but you'll have to rewrite parts of your app. Using Pickle for data persistance, especially involving much data, is not a good pratice.

Comment: PolyModel would be a good thing to check out in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The key advantages of using Django are its ORM and template system.  The ORM is not very useful with datastore because of its non-relational nature and the template system is available as part of the app engine to be used with webapp.

I have had good success with using webapp and django templates for our project.